# "Eat is to feed as hear is to ..."

Tags: vocabulary

I think the title says all! To make someone `eat` is `feed`. What is the word for `to make someone hear`? Now `tell` or `say` will not do, because they do not `make someone hear`; whether to pay heed to the speaker or not is up to the person being talked to. So I need a word that sort of forces someone to `hear` what I say (kind of shouting near the ear to make him listen, eh?)

Comment: No, you don't. "speak" , "tell ", or "say" are fine. Feeding someone is not the same as forcing them to eat. That is called "force-feeding".  Have you ever tried to feed a baby who does not want to eat?

Comment: To piggy-back on what @Brian said, you could say that to _help_ someone eat is to "feed".

Answer (score 1):

> So I need a word that sort of forces someone to hear what I say, (kind
>   of shouting near the ear to make him listen, eh?)

In English, we say with an impatient tone in our voice:

**Do I have to *spoon-feed* this to you?**

and we mean by that:

*Are you not going to pay attention and make some real effort to understand this?*

Comment: But however, when you write you can't *write* your voice on the paper :-)